# How to share dynamic object of arrays among components in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to implement a configuration feature in which an object of arrays can be shared among components. However, I am struggling to make it such that whenever an array from the object is selected, it will not be displayed in the rest of the components which utilize the object.

```
const initGestures = [
    { desc: 'Left swipe', id: 0, selectedBy: null },
    { desc: 'Right swipe', id: 1, selectedBy: null },
    { desc: 'Up swipe', id: 2, selectedBy: null },
    { desc: 'Down swipe', id: 3, selectedBy: null },
    { desc: 'Grab', id: 4, selectedBy: null },
    { desc: 'Pinch', id: 5, selectedBy: null }
]
```

In my case, it is a set of gestures that will be used by the Gesture component.

```
<Gesture    
    index={index}    
    gestures={this.state.gestures}    
    gesturePool={this.gesturePool} 
/>
```

I've passed in a function into the components which will be receiving the object, and updating which of the arrays are being used by which component.

```
gesturePool = (gestureId, ownerId) => {
        //Copy of state
        const gestureList = this.state.gestures

        //Targeted gesture
        const targetGesture = this.state.gestures[gestureId]

        //Iterate through gestures to find if there are existing gestures mapped to owner ID
        //If so, set selectedBy of gesture to null
        gestureList.filter((gesture, index) => {
            if(gesture.selectedBy === ownerId) gestureList.splice(index, 1, {...gesture, selectedBy: null})
        })

        //Assign owner ID to new gesture ID
        gestureList.splice(gestureId, 1, {...targetGesture, selectedBy: ownerId})

        //Map updated list to state
        this.setState({gestures: gestureList})
 }
```

The selected gesture will be mapped to the component that chooses it via the index that is passed in.

```
<select className="custom-dropdown" id="gesture" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}>
    {
        gestures ? gestures.map((gesture) => {
        if(gesture.selectedBy === null || gesture.selectedBy === index) {
            return <option key={index} value={gesture.id}>{gesture.id}</option>
        }
        }) : null
    }
</select>
```

This initially works, but when new Gesture components are mounted, I receive an error with the dropdown values duplicating.

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

What is the workaround to this?

Comment: `gestures.map((gesture) =>` Where is `index`?

Comment: The index used is the one that is being passed into the Gesture component itself. The index being used is the ownerID that is used in the gesturePool() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select className="custom-dropdown" id="gesture" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}>
    {
        gestures ? gestures.map((gesture,idx) => {
        if(gesture.selectedBy === null || gesture.selectedBy === index) {
            return <option key={idx} value={gesture.id}>{gesture.id}</option>
        }
        }) : null
    }
</select>
```

Try it.

I think you should use another `index` as Unique keys

Comment: Every gesture have an `id`, you should use it instead of index

Comment: @LeonKho React uses keys to identify changes and to know what element needs an update

Comment: @AsafAviv yeah, you are also right, if that `id` are unique.

Comment: You are right, I've used the wrong index to map to the option tags. It should be as Asaf has pointed, each option key should correspond to the id that I've provided. Thank you so much for pointing it out!